# Solve trig integral $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \left(\frac{\sin5x}{\sin x}\right)^2 \,dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I've stumbled across this integral: $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \left(\frac{\sin5x}{\sin x}\right)^2 \,dx $$

I was on a time limit and my intuition told me: $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \left(\frac{\sin5x}{\sin x}\right)^2 \,dx  = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}5dx= 5x\Big|_0^{\pi/2}=\frac{5\pi}{2}$$

which turned out to be the right answer.

I'd like to know the correct way of integrating such a function. I've tried several techniques and all of them failed (just started integrals in my calc 1 class).

And is it just a coincidence that the first equality sign above hold or is there some explanation to it?

Comment: Try the quintuple Angle formula, and you will find that you only need to compute the integral of one of the terms, the other terms because the periodicity is zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per symmetry
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \left(\frac{\sin5x}{\sin x}\right)^2 \,dx =\frac14 \int_{0}^{2\pi} \left(\frac{\sin5x}{\sin x}\right)^2 \,dx $$
With $\frac{\sin5x}{\sin x}=\frac{e^{i5x}- e^{-i5x}}{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}=\sum_{k=-4}^4 e^{i k x}
$
$$I= \frac14 \sum_{k,j=-4}^4\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i(k+j)x}dx=\frac14\int_0^{2\pi}5\ dx= \frac{5\pi}2
$$
where only the five pairs of $k+j=0$ survive the integration over $(0,2\pi)$ due to periodicity.